# Application hang after KERNELBASE call

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc, windbg

My multithreading MFC application, on a production environment, sometimes hang.
After these events we have forced dumps from task manager.

From the first dump, using windbg and/or visual studio, on the main thread I have something like this:

```
.  0  Id: af4.af8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 000007ff`fffde000 Unfrozen
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`0102e368 00000000`7740ac38 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xa
01 00000000`0102e370 00000000`7740ab34 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xe8
02 00000000`0102e420 00000000`77413165 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xd1
03 00000000`0102e450 00000000`77412e53 ntdll!RtlpReferenceCurrentDirectory+0x25
04 00000000`0102e4f0 00000000`77412478 ntdll!RtlGetFullPathName_Ustr+0xa56
05 00000000`0102e640 00000000`7741269a ntdll!RtlpDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_Ustr+0xd8
06 00000000`0102e910 000007fe`fd427acd ntdll!RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus+0x6a
07 00000000`0102e960 00000001`411569ee KERNELBASE!GetFileAttributesExW+0x2d
08 00000000`0102ea30 00000001`41156995 rle!_waccess_s+0x4e [minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\filesystem\waccess.cpp @ 23] 
09 00000000`0102ea90 00000001`4039fb30 rle!_waccess+0x9 [minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\filesystem\waccess.cpp @ 54] 
0a 00000000`0102eac0 00000001`403a0e99 rle!WriteStringOnLogFile+0x150 [C:\usr\work\hq\COMMON_APP.CPP @ 3300] 
0b 00000000`0102f070 00000001`401e4107 rle!WriteStringOnLogFile+0xc9 [C:\usr\work\hq\COMMON_APP.CPP @ 3253] 
0c 00000000`0102f0d0 00000001`404e7d8c rle!CBlisterView::LavoroDopoStopMacchina+0x937 [C:\usr\work\hq\BLISTVW.CPP @ 15185]
```

Another thread due, I think, to the lock of the main show me:

```
  14  Id: af4.bd8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 000007ff`fff94000 Unfrozen
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`4475f1c0 00000000`77412e53 ntdll!RtlpReferenceCurrentDirectory+0x40
01 00000000`4475f260 00000000`77412478 ntdll!RtlGetFullPathName_Ustr+0xa56
02 00000000`4475f3b0 00000000`7741269a ntdll!RtlpDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_Ustr+0xd8
03 00000000`4475f680 000007fe`fd424407 ntdll!RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus+0x6a
04 00000000`4475f6d0 00000000`771b0dad KERNELBASE!CreateFileW+0xa7
05 00000000`4475f830 00000001`4115e14d kernel32!CreateFileWImplementation+0x7d
06 00000000`4475f890 00000001`40548fb6 rle!common_stat<_stat64i32>+0x75 [minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\filesystem\stat.cpp @ 463] 
07 00000000`4475f8f0 00000001`4054961f rle!CFileCopyThread::CopiaTuttoInRemoto+0x216 [C:\usr\work\hq\rle\sources\LAVORO.CPP @ 12137]
```

Notice how the functions are the same until the enter in critical section.

Other threads are in WaitForMultipleObjects as expected.

The other dump has similar situation but in a different point of the same function in main thread:

```
.  0  Id: a80.a84 Suspend: 0 Teb: 000007ff`fffde000 Unfrozen
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`0102e5a8 00000000`770e8156 ntdll!NtWaitForKeyedEvent+0xa
01 00000000`0102e5b0 000007fe`fced722d ntdll!RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive+0x106
02 00000000`0102e610 000007fe`fced75fc KERNELBASE!GetTimeZoneInformationCacheForYear+0x14b
03 00000000`0102e6a0 00000001`40f4380d KERNELBASE!SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime+0x48
04 00000000`0102e890 00000001`40f43e06 rle!ATL::CTime::CTime+0x51 [d:\a01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\atltime.h @ 508] 
05 00000000`0102e910 00000001`40f43bb0 rle!CFile::GetStatus+0x122 [d:\a01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\filest.cpp @ 135] 
06 00000000`0102e9c0 00000001`40f2a00f rle!CFile::GetFilePath+0x3c [d:\a01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\filest.cpp @ 79] 
07 00000000`0102ec40 00000001`401d68b8 rle!CArchive::CArchive+0x67 [d:\a01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\arccore.cpp @ 248] 
08 00000000`0102eca0 00000001`403e3980 rle!CBlisterDoc::OnSaveDocument+0x1f8 [C:\usr\work\hq\rle\sources\BLISTDOC.cpp @ 335] 
09 00000000`0102ede0 00000001`401e4644 rle!CBlisterView::SaveDocument+0xc70 [C:\usr\work\hq\rle\sources\COMMON_VIEW.CPP @ 4498] 
0a 00000000`0102f0d0 00000001`404e7d8c rle!CBlisterView::LavoroDopoStopMacchina+0xe74 [C:\usr\work\hq\rle\sources\BLISTVW.CPP @ 15270]
```

From my understanding low level core function are waiting for something but I don't understand why.

Can this kind of problem happen randomly after a memory corruption?

How can I understand more about these kind of issues and understand the root cause of a problem like this?

Is there any tool or technique that I can use to understand better?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879506/critical-section-hang-analysis-with-windbg